# Do all spellcasting classes get unlimited cantrips?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I at least know that Wizards get to use level-0 spells an unlimited number of times a day, but is this a class feature, or are all cantrips unlimited use? I ask this because some spontaneous spellcasting classes still have a limited number of slots for level 0 spells, even if they aren't capable of learning that many spells of that level, and was wondering if they are limited use for those classes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**No, and wizards don't either.**

Wizards *learn* all cantrips available to them automatically, but they are restricted by their prepared spell slots per day in cantrips as with every other level of spell. This slots-per-day limit is true of all other casters (spontaneous or prepared-type) with access to 0-level spells of any sort; the advantage wizards get is only in knowing all of the cantrips, not in being able to use them as often as they like.

[NB: Both Pathfinder and 5e *do* implement unlimited cantrips, which may be a source of confusion.]